# How to add List<Future<Object>> into Set<Object>?

Tags: java, multithreading

during the development of ExecutorService, it became necessary to put List  in Set . How can this be done?

```
public class Executor {
    private Set<List<Future<Object>>> primeNumList = Collections.synchronizedSet(new TreeSet<>());

    Set<List<Future<Object>>> getPrimeNumList() {
        return primeNumList;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void setup(int min, int max, int threadNum) throws InterruptedException {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadNum);
        List<Callable<Object>> callableList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < threadNum; i++) {
            callableList.add(new AdderImmediately(min + i, max, threadNum));
        }
        List<Future<Object>> a = executorService.invokeAll(callableList);
        primeNumList.add(a); // here i try to add Future list into Set
        System.out.println(primeNumList);
        executorService.shutdown();
    }
```

My class in which I process the values ​​and return them via call (). After that they fall into the List  from where I want them to be placed in the final Set

```
public class AdderImmediately implements Callable {
    private int minRange;
    private int maxRange;
    private Set<Integer> primeNumberList = new TreeSet<>();
    private int step;

    AdderImmediately(int minRange, int maxRange, int step) {
        this.minRange = minRange;
        this.maxRange = maxRange;
        this.step = step;
    }

    @Override
    public Object call() {
        fillPrimeNumberList(primeNumberList);
        return primeNumberList;
    }

    private void fillPrimeNumberList(Set<Integer> primeNumberList) {
        for (int i = minRange; i <= maxRange; i += step) {
            if (PrimeChecker.isPrimeNumber(i)) {
               primeNumberList.add(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it somehow possible to implement? Because what I have now, I get a ClassCastException. Or am I not understanding something?)

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
    at java.util.TreeMap.compare(TreeMap.java:1294)
    at java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:538)
    at java.util.TreeSet.add(TreeSet.java:255)
    at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.add(Collections.java:2035)
    at Executor.setup(Executor.java:22)
    at Demo.main(Demo.java:47)
```

Comment: you have list of futures why do you want to add it to another set ??

Comment: Where in your code are you trying to add the `List` to a `Set`?

Comment: I noted this in the code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not able to catch the error at compile time because you have used `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`. On removing that, there's a compile warning at this statement: `callableList.add(new AdderImmediately(min + i, max, threadNum));`

The second problem is, you haven't used generic form while creating `AdderImmediately` class. You are clearly returning, `Set<Integer>` type from the `call` method. If you use the proper generic form in your case, i.e., `Callable<Set<Integer>>`, the problem becomes clear in the above line. The type of `callableList` is `List<Callable<Object>>`. You [cannot add an element of type `Callable<Set<Integer>>` into it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2745301/9080015).

Because you had added the elements of incorrect type by suppressing generic warnings, you are getting `ClassCastException` at runtime.

I'd recommend you to read the chapters on Generics from Effective Java 3rd edition to better understand these concepts.

Comment: Wow. Simply amazing answer. Thanks